# Java web application error, probably in web.xml

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I created a Hello World servlet, and ran it on a local server using tomcat.. It ran fine.

Then, I tried mapping it to a url pattern, and the page shows error `The requested resource (/hello) is not available.`

can someone help me please. Just starting out on Java EE. any good resources to learn/practice also appreciated.

my hello world servlet is located in : 
`workspace\TestServletsApplication\src\com\msusevusal`

my web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

<display-name>TestServletsApplication</display-name>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.msusevusal.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: what is the URL you are trying to hit?

Comment: running on a local server, 
http://localhost:8080/hello

Comment: can you post the contents of your servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is your tomcat configuration?
if you place your app in the %tomcat_home%/webapps dir, then the url should be
localhost:8080/appName/hello

Comment: @r don't set the name of the question to 'solved', just accept the answer.